# Node.js v18.3.0 "Export" and "Import" VS Code not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

Attempting to export a class and use as an extention for another class.. I've even tried module.export at the bottom and export class at the top. What am I doing wrong? Also tried changing to .mjs

File: -animal.js -dog.js -test.js

animal.js:

```
class Animal {
....
    
}

export {Animal}
```

dog.js:

```
import {Animal} from 'animal.js';

class Dog extends Animal{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much setup details to go on, but one thing I noticed is your import path is absolute... which is generally reserved for node modules

```
import {Animal} from 'animal.js';
```

I'd expect it to be relative, more like

```
import {Animal} from '../animal';
or
import {Animal} from './animal';
```